# How can I build the environment for html in sublime Text3?

Tags: javascript, html, sublimetext3

Question :

> How can I build environment for HTML in Sublime Text3?

My operating system is Windows 10 and I use Sublime Text3. I'd like to use St3 to run HTML code, but it can't. What can I do?

I tried some coding, but failed.

**code**

```
function test(arg){
            console.log(arg);
        }

test("hello JaveScript!");
```

**Error:** SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Sublime Text is not an IDE, there are other tools like Webstorm or vscode that will do what you want

Comment: If you want to use Sublime Text you need Xampp for the server. If you prefer to code easier then use an IDE with the server inside or add one by yourself.